# Equivalent of java.io.Writer class in .NET

Tags: java, vb.net, printing

I am writing functionality to print out pages in Visual Basic and have found suitable classes with helpful methods in Java, the `java.io.Writer` class. I was wondering if there were a similar class with similar methods in Visual Basic?

Comment: `System.IO` has many IO functions.  I cant say how similar they are to java

Answer (score 1):

The [`System.IO.StreamWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.streamwriter) may help you.

But if you're looking for the abstract equivilent of the `java.io.Writer` abstract class it would be [`System.IO.TextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.textwriter).

A good resource whenever you need to find information for .NET classes is the [MSDN Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) site provided by Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your productive response, you've been a great help.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted, it answers the question. Yes the question was simple, maybe the asker for whatever reason didn't know where to look. If the downvoter could explain what could be done to improve this answer that would be helpful.